# I want to get the text content of an element inside $(this) on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, event-listener

```
function newFunc(){
  excuseDivs = " "
  excuseArrayItem = excuse + " : " + "<span class='excuseDivTime'>" + endTime + "</span>";
  excuseArray.unshift(excuseArrayItem)
  excuseArray.forEach(function(excuse){
  excuseDivs +="<div class='excuse-div'>"+excuse+"</div>"
})
```

I want to add a click listener to the div that this function creates. I want that click listener to get the text content of the span inside the div (class of excuseDivTime). Is there some way to get something like `($(this) > span).textContent ??`

Comment: Could you provide a complete, but minimal example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly easy in either plain JavaScript or stick with jQuery.

You need to query for the span under the clicked div.

If you are using jQuery, stick with jQuery method calls e.g. `.text()` instead of `.textContent`.

```js
// Plain JavaScript
document.getElementById('MyDiv').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert(e.currentTarget.querySelector('span').textContent);
});

// jQuery Version
$('#MyDiv').on('click', function(e) {
  alert($(this).find('span').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MyDiv">Click me! <span>This text will show in an alert.</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) or [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.excuse-div', function() {
   console.log( $(this).find('.excuseDivTime').text() );    
});
```